# Assistance in building a query fro calulate avg(), before a month, and after a month

Tags: sql-server

I have to write a query where for every customer and every month of 2009, calculate the average purchase before each month, after each month, and show a list with the customers and months, where the average purchase after each month is > from the average purchase before the month.

Example of what it should show :

```
name         month    avgBefore   avgAfter         
P.Anderson     3          13         35
```

My problem is, while it is rather easy to create the view v1 which contains (name, code, month, avgAmount) (a list to show name, avg purchases for each month), I do not know (or rather I can't imagine) how to do the rest (calculate avg before/after each month) .

Ex: avereagebefore month 3 = sum(all avg from month 1 to 3), avereageAfter month 3 = sum(all avg from 3 to max(month)

Can someone please help me ?

The view V1 is like this (as shown when you edit the view in Management Studio)

```
SELECT     
    c.name, c.code, 
    MONTH(t.DateTime) AS minas, 
    AVG(t.charged_amount) AS total
FROM
    dbo.customers AS c 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.accounts AS a ON c.code = a.customer_code 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.creditcard AS cc ON a.acc_number = cc.acc_number 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.transactions AS t ON cc.cc_number = t.cc_number 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.shop AS s ON t.shop_code = s.shop_code
WHERE
    (YEAR(t.DateTime) = 2009)
GROUP BY 
    c.name, c.code, MONTH(t.DateTime)
```

I tried to separate each month in a view ( like created 12 views :S )

Ex:

```
create view [Dec](name, code, minas, averg)
as 
    select * from v1 
    where minas = 12
```

and then did this :

```
select 
    v1.name, v1.code, v1.minas, sum(total)
from 
    v1, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, [Dec]
where 
    v1.minas <= Jan.minas or v1.minas <= Feb.minas or 
    v1.minas <= Mar.minas or v1.minas <= Apr.minas or
    v1.minas <= May.minas or v1.minas <= Jun.minas or
    v1.minas <= Jul.minas or v1.minas <= Aug.minas or
    v1.minas <= Sep.minas or v1.minas <= Oct.minas or
    v1.minas <= Nov.minas or v1.minas <= [Dec].minas 
group by 
    v1.name,v1.code,v1.minas
```

but it didn't work.

Also for a test I tried :

```
select 
    v1.name, v1.code, v1.minas, sum(v1.total)
from 
    v1, Jan as v2, Feb as v3
where 
    v1.code = v2.code and v1.code = v3.code
group by 
    v1.name, v1.code, v1.minas
```

but the result was

```
Nelson J. Arredondo 100606 1 75
Nelson J. Arredondo 100606 2 100
Nelson J. Arredondo 100606 5 250
```

in month 2, it should have been 175 and in month 5 250+175

Can you please help me figuring this out ?

Comment: I think before doing SQL, you most clarify the statistic background. avereagebefore month 3 = sum(all avg from month 1 to 3). 1) perhaps you just choose a misleading name here, I would exclude month 3 and use the monthes 1 and 2 here. 2) Using just the sum of averages doesn't give somezhing comparable, I would at least devide By 2. And in praxis I would just use just the avarage in the range before.

Comment: the above was just an example on what the query must return. Actuallu the view V1, has fore each month and each customer, the average purchase. Also what i tried to do above, was to sum all the average of each customer for the previous months. lets say that Nelson J. Arredondo had average purchase 75 for january and 100 in February. Then the average purchase before february was 75 and after february was 175. In the same way for May, the average purchase before mat is 75+100=175. and after may is 75+100+250=375

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the averages for each user in one row and use UNPIVOT (requires SQL-Server 2005 or later) to transform this into the desired format with one row per month and user.